Fixing a metal shopfront exterior door
I'm volunteering at a charity, and their main door drags across the ground due to seeming to have dropped. There is only one little access panel at the top pictured, and I didn't want to touch it until I know what I am dealing with and know the solution. Can anybody offer a solution and help?




Is that first image a closer mechanism or the hinge point?

Both. This looks like a center-pivot door, which would account for the tape around it to seal it up.

Looking at the door from the outside [outside meaning the space the door panel swings in to], the door is out of square if there is more space between the door and the frame on the handle side than on the hinge side. If the space is consistent across the top, the threshold at the bottom of the door is shimmed incorrectly.
If the door appears square at the top, try lowering the threshold by tightening the  screws.  If that doesn't work you must remove the screw, adjust the shim underneath if there is one, and reinstall the screw.
To square the door, get a step stool and look for a slotted screw in the top rail on the handle side of the door. The screw pushes against a block that is wedged between the door panel and the glass insert. Turn the screw in to raise the door. A shot of lubricant against the screw before adjusting won't hurt. It may be easier if you first lever the door panel up from the bottom to see if you can manually close the gap. This takes pressure off the screw at the top, making it easier to turn.
